# copy existing image and rename with php

Tags: php, image, file, user-profile

I have a little blackout with the simplest of the simplest.

I have a folder called "userpics" and in that folder there are 100x100 profile images named e.g. user-25.jpg. In that folder there also is a picture called user-none.jpg with a silhouette, used as a picture on a comments function when non-registered users posts a comment.

What I want to do is when a user is registered the user-none.jpg (with the silhouette) is copied and named e.g. user-26.jpg. The user can then later upload a new profile image from his account.

I just can't figure out how to copy the image. I tried this:

```
function CreateDummyProfileImage($user_id) {

        $new_dummy = "images/userpics/user-".$user_id.".jpg";

        $dummy = "images/userpics/user-none.jpg";

        list($current_width, $current_height) = getimagesize($dummy);

        $this->imageSizeH = 100;
        $this->imageSizeW = 100;

        $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($this->imageSizeW,  $this->imageSizeH);
        $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($dummy);

        imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $current_width, $current_height);
        imagejpeg($canvas, $new_dummy, 100);   
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

SOLVED :

```
/**********************************************************
     * Create a user with the basic info the user posted
     * in the creation form.
     * 
     * @param string    | The name of the user
     * @param string    | The users email address
     * @param string    | The password to login with
     **********************************************************/
    function CreateUser($name, $email, $password) { 

        /***
         * First we need no check if the email already exists in the system.
         * The statement right below will do that
         ***/
        $check_if_user_exists_sql = $this->db->selectSQL("email", "tdic_users", "email = '".$email."'");
        $check_if_user_exists_result = $this->db->SQLquery($check_if_user_exists_sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($check_if_user_exists_result) > 0) {
            $this->main->txtOutput("The user with email ". $email ." is already registered", "TXT_ERR"); //The email already exists in the system! No further processing from here!
        } else {

            /*** If the email couldn't be found we will create a new user ***/

            /*** Array containing the fields required for user creation ***/
            $fields = array(
                "name" => $name, 
                "email" => $email, 
                "password" => $this->main->SaltMe(sha1($password)), 
                "user_date_created" => time(), //The current time
                "user_last_logged_in" => 0,
                "profileimage" => "user-none.jpg" //SET THIS INSTEAD OF COPYING THE AND RENAMING THE IMAGE
                );

            $create_user_sql = $this->db->insertSQL('tdic_users', $fields);
            $create_user_result = $this->db->SQLquery($create_user_sql);

            if($create_user_result) {
                $this->ActivationMail($name, $email);
                $this->main->txtOutput("You are now registered. In shorty you will recieve an email with an activation link. Please click that link to activate your account.", "TXT_OK"); //Everything went well - we will tell the user that!                
            } else {
               $this->main->txtOutput("An error occured", "TXT_ERR"); //Whoops! Something went wrong! This is unexpected!
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: wrong arguments in [`imagecopy()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) and  [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - seems a decent enough question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to go near GD functions for this - you can just [copy the file](http://www.php.net/copy).

```
function CreateDummyProfileImage($user_id) {
    $res = copy("images/userpics/user-none.jpg", "images/userpics/user-".$user_id.".jpg");
    return 'image'.($res ? '' : ' not').' created';
}
```

However, the model you describe isn't exactly optimal - copying a file countless times. Beter would be to conditionally show one file or the other at the point of output:

```
$user_pic = 'path_to_user_pic.jpg';
$user_pic = file_exists($user_pic) ? $user_pic : 'path_to_silhouette.jpg';
```

Comment: Arh... Of course! I didn't think of it that way! :)
I can upon user registration set the user image to user-none.jpg and just update that field when the user uploads a new image! 
Less is more!
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have edited my question with the solution based on your answer :)

"profileimage" => "user-none.jpg" //SET THIS INSTEAD OF COPYING THE AND RENAMING THE IMAGE is what did the magic!

Comment: I have used this code, but it copy only the names in text, not in the integers. Eg: i have the image names 168519.jpg , 20121206-145501.jpg , bigimages.jpg. It copy the last image only. Can you give any solution for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stream copy is relatively faster

```
function stream_copy($src, $dest)
{
    $fsrc = fopen($src,'r');
    $fdest = fopen($dest,'w+');
    $len = stream_copy_to_stream($fsrc,$fdest);
    fclose($fsrc);
    fclose($fdest);
    return $len;
}
```